# Angular Display Data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form with a dropdown element. The value of the options in the select are IDs from another table. When I click save/add, I save the data to the server, and I add the data to a dynamic table under the form.

In the table I want to display the corresponding name, as in the dropdown element, but I only have the ID which was saved. What is the best method or common practices to display the name?

Example:

Dropdown:

```
1: Jackson Middle School
2: St Thomas High School
3: Jackson High School
```

Display table using ng-repeat:

```
{{school}} *Displays 1,2,3 not 'Jackson Middle School'
```

Comment: We will need to see more of your code to help you, but i suspect that you will need to modify your ng-repeat statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you send a GET request with the following result:

```
[
    {
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"Jackson Middle School"
    },
    {
        "Id":2,
        "Name":"St Thomas High School"
    },
    {
        "Id":3,
        "Name":"Jackson High School"
    }
]
```

and you assign this to **$scope.Schools**,  you should be able to use it like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="school in Schools">{{ school.Name }}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created an array "school_names = [1: Jackson Middle School, 2: St Thomas High School, 3: Jackson High School]" and in the table i just did an array look up {{school_names[school]]}}